# How to reason about the properties of a relation and determine the equivalence quotient.

Tags: abstract-algebra, set-theory

The problem statement is:

$$
\mathbb{R}[x] \text{ is a set of real-valued Polynomials and } R\subseteq\mathbb{R}[x]\times\mathbb{R}[x]\text{ defined as: }
$$
$$
(f(x),g(x)) \in R \iff \exists z \in \mathbb{C}|f(z)=g(z)=0
$$

The question asks to discuss the properties for R.

Usually, I would start by using the definition directly as such:

- Serial: For each $x$ there exist a $y$ such that $f(x)=f(y)=0$.
- Reflexive...
- Symmetry...

The second question is how to determine the quotient $\mathbb{R}[x]/S$ of the equivalence closure.

I don't get how to go about solving it. Could you give me any help, hint, or resources on where to learn more about these kinds of problems?

Comment: First and foremost, you won't go far if you don't use the actual definitions. For instance, $R$ is serial if and only if for all $f$ there is some $g$ such that there is some $z\in\Bbb C$ such that $f(z)=g(z)=0$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio as I explained above I started working from the definition. But I didn't know how to reason with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Surely you are not asked to determine *all* properties of $R$! That would be an infinite list.

I am assuming you want to know whether it's an equivalence relation. Starting with the definition is a good idea. Is this relation reflexive? That is, is there for every real polynomial $f$ a real polynomial $g$  such that $f$ and $g$ have a (complex) root in common? Clearly not, for if $f$ is a non-zero constant it has no roots at all.

Is $R$ symmetric? That is, if $f$ has a root $z$ in common with $g$, does $g$ have a root in common with $f$? Yes, of course! Just take the same $z$.

Is $R$ transitive? That is, if $f$ has a root $z$ in common with $g$ and $g$ has a root $z'$ in common with $h$, do $f$ and $h$ have a root in common? Not necessarily; I'll leave it to you to find a counterexample.

Now the equivalence closure $S$ of $R$ is the smallest equivalence relation which contains $R$. This means a.o. that if $(f,g),(g,h)\in R$, then also $(f,h)\in R$. Using this, one can show that for every non-constant polynomial $f$ we have $(0,f),(f,0)\in R$.

I encourage you to try your hand at proving this and finding the set of equivalence classes with respect to $S$ yourself.

Comment: For the transitive property does the following counterexample work: 
$f(x)=(x+1)^2$ and $g(x)=x^2-1$ and $h(x)=(x-1)^2$. We have a common root between $f$ and $g$ = -1, then between $g$ and $h$ =1 but we don't have a common root between $f$ and $h$ for any x.
Is this correct?

Comment: I don't get the equivalence closure $S$. You stated that (correctly by the definition of equivalence) it has the transitive property. What about the reflexive closure? 
And I don't get why we need to show that (0,),(,0)∈.

Comment: Your example for non-transitivity of $R$ seems to be correct. In the equivalence closure of $R$, any two non-constant polynomials $f$ and $g$ are equivalent. One way to show this is by showing that they are all equivalent to $0$ and using the fact that $S$ must be transitive. What is the smallest equivalence relation $T$ for which all non-constant polynomials are equivalent to $0$? Well, the one where $(f,g)\in T$ if and only if either $f=g$ or both $f$ and $g$ are non-constant polynomials or $0$. Does $T$ contain $R$?